# Fastest MySQL row rank of big table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

**Info**: I have this table (*PERSONS*):

```
PERSON_ID   int(10)
POINTS      int(6)
4 OTHER COLUMNS which are of type int(5 or 6)
```

The table consist of 25M rows and is growing 0.25M a day. The distribution of points is around 0 to 300 points and 85% of the table has 0 points.

**Question**: I would like to return to the user which rank he/she has if they got at least 1 point. How and where would be the fastest way to do it, in **SQL** or **PHP** or **combination**?

**Extra Info**: Those lookups can happen every second 100 times. The solutions I have seen so far are not fast enough, if more info needed please ask.

Any advice is welcome, as you understand I am new to PHP and MySQL :)

Comment: You are not giving enough information about your use case. Why would you need PHP to do this? This is a simple MySQL statement, unless you are referring to performance issues.

Comment: What is more frequent, ranking a user or inserting new rows? At about what ratio?

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to MySQL, will add some more info to the question now.

Comment: What sort of distribution of points do you get above 0 points, (say for 1 to 10 points)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an index on `t(points)` and on `t(person_id, points)`.  Then run the following query:

```
select count(*)
from persons p
where p.points >= (select points from persons p where p.person_id = <particular person>)
```

The subquery should use the second index as a lookup.  The first should be an index scan on the first index.

Sometimes MySQL can be a little strange about optimization.  So, this might actually be better:

```
select count(*)
from persons p cross join
     (select points from persons p where p.person_id = <particular person>) const
where p.points > const.points;
```

This just ensures that the lookup for the points for the given person happens once, rather than  for each row.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html) your table into two partitions - one for people with 0 points and one for people with one or more points.
2. Add one index on points to your table and another on person_id (if these indexes don't already exist).

To find the dense rank of a specific person, run the query:

```
select count(distinct p2.points)+1
from person p1
join person p2 on p2.points > p1.points
where p1.person_id = ?
```

To find the non-dense rank of a specific person, run the query:

```
select count(*)
from person p1
join person p2 on p2.points >= p1.points
where p1.person_id = ?
```

(I would expect the dense rank query to run significantly faster.)

Comment: Thanks +1, works good, but Gordon's query was just a little faster